# For full disk LUKS encryption, is the swap partition encrypted?

Tags: encryption, luks

18.04.1

I went with full disk encryption. Does this mean I need to concern myself with the swap partition or is that encrypted also? I was expecting "Full Disk" to mean the whole disk including all partitions but this has recently come into question by a third party.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2357927

Comment: Thx. Mine is not encrypted. :-(  Re-post as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2357927:

`lsblk` will show the relationship between partitions and their containers. For example:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                             8:0    0 55.9G  0 disk  
├─sda1                          8:1    0  487M  0 part  /boot
├─sda2                          8:2    0    1K  0 part  
└─sda5                          8:5    0 55.4G  0 part  
  └─sda5_crypt                252:0    0 55.4G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--mate--vg-root   252:1    0 51.5G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--mate--vg-swap_1 252:2    0    4G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

Here you can see that the swap partition is within a dm-crypt container, and hence it is encrypted.

Comment: Awesome. This came up in an interview recently and I had no answer. Remembered the issue but hadn't looked in an age.